# flutter - how to resume playing video from previous duration with Chewie controller?

Tags: flutter, video-player

I have used the Chewie video player plugin to implement a video player.

1. I want to save the duration when the video is paused/ exit from the video screen  and
2. resume playing from the exact duration the next time I visit the video screen.

   ```
   class VideoPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
    _VideoPlayerScreenState createState() => _VideoPlayerScreenState();

   final String video_link;
    VideoPlayerScreen({Key key, @required this.video_link}) : super(key: key);
   }

   class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {

     VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
     ChewieController _chewieController;

   @override
   void initState() {
   super.initState();
   _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(
       widget.video_link)..initialize().then((_){setState(() {});
       });
   _chewieController = ChewieController(
     allowedScreenSleep: false,
     allowFullScreen: true,
     deviceOrientationsAfterFullScreen: [
       DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
       DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
       DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
       DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
     ],
     videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
     aspectRatio: 16/9,
     looping: true,
     showControls: true,
   );
   _chewieController.addListener(() {
     if (_chewieController.isFullScreen) {
       SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
         DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
         DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
       ]);
     }
   });}


   @override
   void dispose() {
   _videoPlayerController.dispose();
   _chewieController.dispose();
   SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
     DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
     DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
     DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
     DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
   ]);
   super.dispose();}
   ```

Comment: have you found any solution??